# System freezes during booting everytime (Ubuntu 14.10)

Tags: boot, grub2

Acer aspire E5-571G-36L5

Message: "Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!"

Already tried:

- That libre office quick start is disabled
- Different options in gru config file item GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT (acpi=off, acpi=force, boot=bios, boot=pci)
- boot-repair (result: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10129603/)

all of that change nothing. I can only boot in recovery mode.

Please help anybody and thanks in advance.